# Laravel multi level authentication

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working with a existing laravel project. So on that project the previous one install two auth folder, one for admin and clients. Now my role is adding a seller part. I create separated model and controller for seller part, but when i try to login with seller email and password by any how system search seller email into client database table.
This code for my seller login:

```
$credentials = $request->only('seller_email','seller_password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('seller.dashboard'));

        }
        return redirect()->intended(route('seller.login'));
```

But it searching into the clients table Why?

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'seller_email'
>   in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `clients` where `seller_email` =
>   dr@seller.com limit 1);

Config/Auth.php file looks like

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],
        'seller' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'sellers',
        ]
    ],
'providers' => [
        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        'sellers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Seller::class,
        ]
    ],
```

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Comment: Can you please share the client table structure?

Comment: I added clients table structure into my quenstion.

Comment: In which table should your code search for the authentication details? Btw, your question has nothing to do with mysql. The mysql error is a symptom and not the cause. The laravel code doing the authentication is incorrect - you are probably pointing it to the wrong table or passing the wrong parameters to it.

Comment: Sellers table by using the ORM but when i hit login button it took credentials and search into clients table. why i dont know?

Comment: Then you are routing the Auth:: attempt() incorrectly, but your question does not show its configuration.

Comment: please post config/auth.php . the last developer has probably added providers for each group

Comment: Fatemeh Majd please check above I added config/Auth.php

Answer (score 0):

use seller guard while attempting to login as

```
if (Auth::guard('seller')->attempt($credentials)){
        return redirect()->intended(route('seller.dashboard'));

    }
```

Comment: After using this code, if  i entered wrong or right password, it takes me to dashboard. @Khadga shrestha

Comment: Seller Model to check if you implement authenticable or not